# SNMP: Create custom OID

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, snmp

I need custom OIDs for monitoring some of my software states.
But I just can't understand: how can I create custom OID (like .1.3.6.1.4.1.30891.100.103) in Windows XP system?
I need few of them to write there some info and read it when needed but I have no idea how to create them in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this by writing an extension of Windows SNMP agent. The following article shows how,

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SNMP_Agent_DLL__Part1_.aspx

Comment: I once created a simple guide that might help
https://github.com/ahmednawazkhan/guides/blob/master/snmp/creating-custom-mib.md

Answer (score 7):

There are a few options to register OIDs, including:

- [Private Enterprise Numbers](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) (which are then [publicly listed](http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers))
- [UUID-based OIDs](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/uuid.html)

In both cases, this defines a prefix and you can do what you want with the rest of the tree.

I'd suggest reading this as well if you're not sure what to choose: http://www.oid-info.com/faq.htm (more specifically "[How to get an OID assigned?](http://www.oid-info.com/faq.htm#10)").

Comment: But how can I add them in to the system? I mean: if I register it on any of these sites it won't appear in my system and I have no idea how to add it there.

Comment: Not sure, maybe something along these lines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393621%28VS.85%29.aspx